# inclusion of connected manifold of dimension $\geq 3$ minus point induces isomorphism of fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

The following is problem 10-6 of John M. Lees' Introduction to Topological manifolds:

> Suppose $M$ is a connected manifold of dimension $n \geq 3$, and $p \in M$. Show that the inclusion $M\backslash \{p\} \hookrightarrow M$ induces an isomorphism $\pi_1(M\backslash \{p \}) \cong \pi_1(M)$

I can see that these fundamental groups are isomorphic by the van Kampen Theorem. Specifically, I can take a neighborhood $U_1$ of $p$ that is homeomorphic to an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and take $U_2$ to be $M\backslash \{p \}$. Both are open and both are path connected (the later is because $M$ is connected). Moreoever, the intersection of these two sets is a ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a point removed and so is simply connected (it is here where we use that $n \geq 3$, as this is not true if $n = 1,2$). Thus, by van Kampen Theorem $\pi_1(M) = \pi_1(M\backslash \{p\})*\pi_1(U_1) $. But, $U_1$ is simply connected so $\pi_1(M) = \pi_1(M\backslash \{p \})$.

What I don't know is why the inclusion is an isomorphism. You can likely get surjectivity by quoting Lemma 7.19 which states that if $M$ is a manifold of dimension $\geq 2$ and $f$ is a path in $M$ from $p_1$ to $p_2$ and $q$ is any point in $M$ other than $p_1$ or $p_2$, then $f$ is path homotopic to a path that does not pass through $q$.

However, I do not know why the induced map should be injective. Any help or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map $\pi_1(M\setminus p) \to \pi_1(M)$ from the van Kampen theorem is already induced by inclusion.

One way of seeing this (from a category theory perspective) is by noting that the van Kampen theorem  actually concerns the *pushout*

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\pi_1(U_1\cap U_2) @>{\iota_1}>> \pi_1(U_2)\\
@V\iota_2VV @V\rho_2 VV \\
\pi_1(U_1) @>\rho_1>> P @>h>> \pi_1(U_1 \cup U_2)
\end{CD}$$

where $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$ are induced by inclusion, and $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are given by the pushout. $P$ is typically denoted $\pi_1(U_1) \ast_{\pi_1(U_1\cap U_2)} \pi_1(U_2)$. The homomorphisms $j_1\colon\pi_1(U_1) \rightarrow \pi_1(U_1 \cup U_2)$ and $j_2\colon\pi_1(U_2) \rightarrow \pi_1(U_1 \cup U_2)$ induced by inclusion agree when precomposed with $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$, so the universal property of the pushout gives us a natural homomorphish $h\colon P \to \pi_1(U_1\cup U_2)$ such that $j_1 = h\circ \rho_1$ and $j_2 = h \circ \rho_2$. The statement of van Kampen is then that (under the appropriate assumptions) $h$ is an isomorphism.

In your particular case, $U_1 \simeq *$, $U_2 = M\setminus p$, and $U_1 \cap U_2 \simeq S^{n-1}$, which is simply-connected when $n\geq 3$. In this case the pushout diagram has a single non-zero morphism $\rho\colon\pi_1(M\setminus p) \to P$, and the universal property reduces to the following statement: given any morphism $f\colon \pi_1(M\setminus p) \to G$ there is a unique morphism $h\colon P \to G$ such that $f = h\circ \rho$. You can use this simplified universal property to give an inverse for $\rho$ and show it is an isomorphism (exercise in universal properties). The homomorphism $i\colon \pi_1(M\setminus p) \to \pi_1(M)$ induced by inclusion gives us (by the universal property of the pushout) a homomorphism $h\colon P \to \pi_1(M)$ with the property that $i = h\circ \rho$, and by van Kampen theorem $h$ is an isomorphism. Therefore the map $\pi_1(M\setminus p) \to \pi_1(M)$ induced by inclusion factors as two isomorphisms.

Comment: How do I know $h$ is an isomorphism? I do not see how we can apply Van Kampen because I do not know what the pushout $P$ is.

Comment: The pushout of this diagram is one way of defining the amalgamated product $\pi_1(U_1) \ast_{\pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2)} \pi_1(U_2)$ (maybe that's the part which is not clear), I've just called it "$P$" for brevity. It's possible we have different statements of the van Kampen theorem, but the one I'm thinking of says there is a natural homomorphism from this amalgamated product to $\pi_1(U_1 \cup U_2)$ given by the universal property, and that this homomorphism is an isomorphism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem).

Comment: I think the main point I was trying to make is that the isomorphism $\pi_1(U_1) \ast_{\pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2)} \pi_1(U_2) \stackrel{\cong}{\to} \pi_1(U_1 \cup U_2)$ given by the van Kampen theorem is induced by the inclusions $U_1 \hookrightarrow U_1\cup U_2 \hookleftarrow U_2$. Since $\pi_1(U_1)\cong \pi_1(U_1 \cap U_2) \cong 0$ in this case, this reduces to simply to the map $\pi_1(M \setminus p) \to \pi_1(M)$ induced by inclusion.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I was not familiar with this statement of the Theorem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: on a much lighter note, how did you learn to make the commutative diagrams in tex?

Comment: Also, Since $P \cong \pi_1(U_1 \cup U_2)$ could you use my argument from above to establish that $\rho$ is an isomorphism? (Eh, on second thought probably not)

Comment: Great question! If you want diagrams in general latex, there are packages like tikzcd and xypic that you should look into. For diagrams specifically on stackexchange, there is a good discussion here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram . One way is to include the AMScd package right above your diagram, and use the syntax specified. Unfortunately there is no way of doing diagonal arrows with the package at the moment, otherwise my diagram would have looked nicer: :)

Comment: A better way to show $\rho$ is an isomorphism is probably to use a more constructive definition of the amalgamated product, then you should be able to see more explicitly why $\pi_1(M\setminus p)$ and $0\ast_0 \pi_1(M\setminus p)$ are the same.

Comment: Okay, Again thank you so much for your help